# Dynamically pass all object's key and value as HTML attributes in VUE template

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, properties

I want to pass an object like `myObj = {id: "personal_info", name:"info", required: true, className: "form-control"}` to either an input, textarea, or select element. The goal is that the object's properties will be the attributes of the HTML element.

Something like:

```
<input v-bind="myObj" >
```

I would like it to generate this:

```
<input id="personal_info" name="info" required="true" class="form-control">
```

I'm building a FormBuilder template to help me generate forms more easily. So my goal is to optimize this process. What I'm doing is this:

```
        <input v-if="element == 'input'"
            :id="cssId" :class="className" :type="type">

        <textarea v-if="element == 'textarea'"
        :id="cssId" :class="className" :rows="rows" :cols="cols">

        </textarea>

        <select v-if="element == 'select'" :id="cssId" :class="className">

            <option v-for="(option, index) in options" :key="index" :value="option.value">
                {{ option.text }}
            </option>
        </select>
```

However, there are many attributes that may not be used. There can be many properties and they may be different (e.g, an input element may have `disabled` or `readonly`, a textarea may have `rows` and `cols`).

Therefore, I cannot simply write them because if they are not used the variable would be undefined and would throw an error. Even if I set a default for all of them, it would be a lot more work because I'd have to write the attribute one by one and that would make a mess in my code. It would also add unnecessary attributes to the elements.

Comment: You answered your own question. `v-bind` would be the suitable way to bind multiple attributes.

Comment: Omg haha that really worked! I had pasted the code that I thought would work but actually I hadn't tried that. I had passed the wrong variable to v-bind, that's why it didn't work before. Thank you very much Cue!!

Comment: If you post it as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You answered your own question. `v-bind` would be the suitable way to bind multiple attributes.